# Fast aggregation of multiple ArrayLists into a single one

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I have the following list:

```
List<ArrayList> list;
```

`list.get(i)` contains the ArrayList object with the following values `{p_name=set1, number=777002}`.

I have to create a

```
Map<key,value>
```

where the key contains the p_name, and values are the numbers.

How to do it easily and fast as there can be hundreds of entries in the initial list and each number can be present in multiple p_name entries.

Update: Here is my current solution

```
 List<Row> list; //here is my data

    Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    for (Row l : list) {
        if (l.hasValues()) {
            Map<String, String> values = l.getResult(); // internal method of Row interface that returns a map
            String key = values.get( "number");
            map.put(key,  values.get( "p_name" ));
        }  
    }
```

The method works, but maybe it could be done better?

PS : There is an obvious error in my design. I wonder if you find it :)

Comment: right now I am looking at possible solutions. The easiest would be to build the list manually but perhaps there is a more optimal way.

Comment: I would first try building that solution and see whether it runs fast enough. If it doesn't, show your attempt and ask for improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine the key can have more then one values, what you are looking for is a MultiMap. [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
Or a simple map in the form

```
  Map<Key,ArrayList<Values>>
```

There is no "fast" way here to me. You still need to iterate through all the elements and check all the values.

And actually hundreds to Java is not much at all